# How to retrieve ID of inserted entry using sqlsrv in PHP

Tags: php, sql-server, sql-server-2014, sqlsrv

I have one query that will return the ID of the inserted row. When I change the query to insert into a different table I only get errors when fetching the identity.  Keep in mind this is the stripped down debugging code of the main program so I can troubleshoot better.

I should also mention that I am using custom wrappers around the sqlsrv commands but they are basically the same. Assume $IC->connection is a connection resource and performing a connection->prepare returns a result stmt object.

```
$upsert_custom = "
INSERT INTO CampusDictionary (attributeID, code, name, seq, active) 
SELECT ?, ?, ?, 0, 1;
SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY();"; // This query will work as expected
$upsert_custom = "
INSERT INTO Person (currentIdentityID, staffNumber, comments) 
SELECT ?, ?, ?;
SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY();"; // Using this query I get errors
$custom_stmt = $IC->connection->prepare( $upsert_custom, array( &$attributeID, &$code, &$name) );

$name = "TEST";
$attributeID = '832';
$code = '9999';

$IC->connection->begin_transaction();
$custom_stmt->execute();
$custom_stmt->next_result();
$custom_stmt->fetch();
$dictionaryID = $custom_stmt->get_field(0);
print_r("THIS WOULD CREATE ID: " . "\r\n");
var_dump($dictionaryID);
die( print_r( $IC->connection->get_errors(), true));
$IC->connection->rollback();
$custom_stmt->cancel();
```

When using the first query only, I get the following output:

```
php test.php
THIS WOULD CREATE ID:
string(5) "16774"
```

When using the second query, I get the following:

```
THIS WOULD CREATE ID:
bool(false)
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => IMSSP
            [SQLSTATE] => IMSSP
            [1] => -14
            [code] => -14
            [2] => An invalid parameter was passed to sqlsrv_get_field.
            [message] => An invalid parameter was passed to sqlsrv_get_field.
        )

)
```

I know that an AFTER INSERT and AFTER UPDATE trigger on the Person table exists but I don't have rights to view these triggers. From what I've read, the SCOPE_IDENTITY shouldn't worry about the trigger anyways.

What is going on here? I need to insert into the Person table and use the ID in another table all within one transaction. I've spent hours troubleshooting this but can't get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

After hours of troubleshooting I finally post here and within 10 minutes I figure it out... I'll leave this here for anyone else that runs into this issue. Perhaps someone smarter than I can explain the WHY.

The solution is to add "SET NOCOUNT ON;" to the beginning of the query. The working code for the second query looks like so:

```
$upsert_custom = "
SET NOCOUNT ON;
INSERT INTO Person (currentIdentityID, staffNumber, comments) 
SELECT ?, ?, ?;
SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY();";
$custom_stmt = $IC->connection->prepare( $upsert_custom, array( &$attributeID, &$code, &$name) );

$name = "TEST";
$attributeID = '832';
$code = '9999';

$IC->connection->begin_transaction();
$custom_stmt->execute();
//$custom_stmt->next_result();//$custom_stmt->next_result();
//$dictionaryID = $custom_stmt->fetch_assoc();
$custom_stmt->fetch();
$dictionaryID = $custom_stmt->get_field(0);
print_r("THIS WOULD CREATE ID: " . "\r\n");
var_dump($dictionaryID);
//die( print_r( $IC->connection->get_errors(), true));
$IC->connection->rollback();
$custom_stmt->cancel();
```

Output of this is:

```
THIS WOULD CREATE ID:
string(5) "43210"
```